# Get a negative voltage from normal DCDC

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I should make a positive-to-negative dc-dc converter.
The specifications are:

- Vin: 2.9V to 7V
- Vout: -3.3V to -15V
- Power:6W

I have seen that it is very difficult to find DCDC (module or chip) with these characteristics, but it becomes very simple if instead of a negative output I need a positive output.
Searching on the internet I came across this module: RPMB12-2.0, which is a DCDC with positive output, but in the datasheet it says that if connected in this way, it can act as a positive to negative converter.
[image]

My question is, can I do this with all DCDC modules/chips?

Let me explain better, if I find a module with the characteristics I need, but with positive output, then: Vin: 2.9V to 7V and Vout: 3.3V to 15V,
If I connect it like in the picture above, can I get a negative output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, can I do this with all DCDC modules/chips?

No. But your converter is a buck converter, and many buck converters can be reconfigured to act as inverting buck-boost converters, yours included.

The following converters can convert an input which is positive with respect to ground to an output which is negative with respect to ground

1. Any converter which is fully isolating. (Simply connect ground to the positive rail of the output. Examples include isolated flyback converters with appropriately isolated feedback.
2. Inverting buck-boost converters
3. Ćuk converters

For each of these types of converters, there are commercial chips which can be used to control them.

Comment: An ordinary buck converter can be used as an inverter also. But it needs a relatively high input voltage rating (greater than the sum of the magnitudes of the input and output voltages in the investing configuration).

Comment: @ThePhoton I haven't looked into it, but can such inverting converters be built using standard commerical buck controller chips?

Comment: @ThePhoton What you describe is an inverting buck-boost converter, which you can make using a standard buck converter controller. Doing so requires level-shifting any control signals, and you'll have to pay some special attention to grounding, but I've done it before. The LTC7149 is a buck controller specifically designed to be used in this way (it has internal level shifters for its control signals).

Comment: The non-isolating LMZ12003 and similar series modules can be wired up to get inverting outputs as well.

Comment: See https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2596.pdf page 12 for example.  The regulator "drives" ground and its own "ground" is pushed down in return. It must be rated for total voltage (input to output).